# Determine if unsigned integer values in struct have been set or not

Tags: c, struct

Imagine you had:

myfile.h

```
typedef struct _myStruct myStruct;

struct _myStruct
{
    uint32_t uData1;
    uint32_t uData2;
    uint32_t uData3;
    /* More data members */
}

void myStructSetData(myStruct * const pMyStruct, const uint32_t uData1, const uint32_t uData2, const uint32_t uData3)
{
    if (!pMyStruct)
        return

    pMyStruct->uData1 = uData1;
    pMyStruct->uData2 = uData2;
    pMyStruct->uData3 = uData3;
}
```

main.c

```
int main(void)
{
    ...
    /* myStructSetData(pMyStruct, 1, 2, 3); */
    ...
    myStructBuild(pMyStruct);
    ...
}
```

I provide myStructSetData() but user might not necessarily use this function to set uData1, 2 and 3.  In myStructBuild() I’d like to know if uData1, 2 and 3 have been set, which I wouldn't be able to unless I initialised them when creating pMyStruct or used bool values like bIsData1Set etc (which I’d like to avoid).

So does it make sense to initialise uData1, uData2 and uData3 to -1?

So in myStructBuild() I would have a check like:

```
if (pMyStruct->uData1 != -1)
{
    /* Include uData1 when building */
}
```

Comment: Not a lot. You basically want some sort of access specifier from what I understood. I'm guessing C++ is out of the question?

Comment: It makes sense to always know the value is *determinate*. I.e. it came from *somewhere* besides the land of ethereal wisps. A *trap value* is ideal (a value that cannot occur in the usage domain you're restricted to, but is none-the-less determinate).

Comment: Are the variable types in the structure fixed size? As in, can you use other types?

Comment: This setup doesn't make sense. If the `struct` is defined inside an implementation file and only forward-declared outside it, then how will the outside construct an instance of it?

Comment: @larsmans-Updated my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either **magic/invalid** values, like **-1** in your post, or, better, use a special flag fields:

```
struct _my_struct
{
    int32_t field1;
    int16_t field2;
    int64_t field3;

    bool    field1_valid;
    bool    field2_valid;
    bool    field2_valid;
};
```

This would simplify coding, especially in case of such examples:

```
struct _my_struct x;
memset(&x, x, sizeof(x));
```

I.e. when resetting all values to zeros, it would make all values **unset**.

Of course, the user will have to set the 'valid' flag:

```
x.field1_valid = 1;
x.field1 = 444;
```

And you can later use a check in your code.

Depending on your needs and preferences, the validity fields can be separate or combined into one bitfield:

```
struct _my_struct
{
    int32_t field1;
    int16_t field2;
    int64_t field3;

    int    field1_valid:1;
    int    field2_valid:1;
    int    field2_valid:1;
};
```

The usage of it is same as above, but the storage size is smaller (if that matters)

Answer (score 0):

If the `uData` variables can have any valid unsigned int value, then no. You can't use `-1`, as it'll just store `UINT_MAX` in the variable (assuming an int is 32bit, that is).

If you'll never need to store more than `UINT_MAX`, and you can change your structure variables type, you could define a larger type if available (e.g. `uint64_t`), in which case you'd be able to store a value higher than the allowed range (such as `-1` converted) to mark as uninitialised. This is the same approach as a file stream returning `-1` at EOF, thus requiring an `int` rather than a `char`.